# VoiceOver reads accessibility label twice when focusing non-UILabel titleView

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover, titleview

I'm encountering a strange issue with VoiceOver.

Goals:

- Set a `UIStackView` containing multiple `UILabel`'s as my `navigationItem.titleView`.
- Mark the stack view as an accessibility element and set its `accessibilityLabel` to an appropriate value.
- Set the stack view as the initial VoiceOver focus by calling `UIAccessibility.post(notification: .screenChanged, argument: navigationItem.titleView)` inside `viewDidAppear(animated:)`.

Expected Result:

- When the view controller appears the focus appears to be on the title view and VoiceOver reads the contents of the accessibility label one time.

Actual Result:

- VoiceOver starts to read the contents of the accessibility label and then part way through (or sometimes after finishing) it proceeds to read it a second time.

This issue does not occur if I set `navigationItem.titleView` to an instance of `UILabel`.

Does anyone know why this happens? Is it a bug in iOS?

I have set up a simple project demonstrating the issue here:
https://github.com/rzulkoski/Focus-TitleView-Bug

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you have a second time reading of your title is in your code.

In your `viewDidLoad`, you set the stackview accessibility label that VoiceOver automatically reads out to inform the user of the changing.

Next, you notify this changing with a post in your `viewDidAppear` that VoiceOver naturally reads out as well.

To prevent from this behavior, just delete `stackView.accessibilityLabel = label.text` in your `setupNavigationItem` function and add this snippet in your private lazy var label init :

```
if (self.view.subviews.contains(stackView)) {
        stackView.accessibilityLabel = label.text
}
```

Updating the `stackView.accessibilityLabel` this way doesn't trigger VoiceOver to inform the user and allows to get your purpose.

However, I don't recommend to read out the title as the first element of a new page unless you [reorder](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#reading-order) the presented elements.

VoiceOver users won't naturally guess that another element is present before the title :

- They may not find a way to get back to the previous page.
- They may be lost if they get the first element of the page with a [4 fingers simple-tap](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/voiceover.html#PageFirstElement) because they'll get the back button and not the title.

Technically, **your problem is solved with the piece of code above** but, conceptually, I suggest to reorder your elements if you still want to expose the title as the first element.

==========

**EDIT (workaround)**

About the technical problem, you're right in your comment, this solution above works thanks to the label reading by VoiceOver.

I commited a solution in your git branch you gave in your initial post.

The problem deals with the UIStackView I cannot explain in this case and cannot solve neither as is.

To reach your purpose, I created a `UIAccessibilityELement` for the stackview that can be perfectly reached and exposed with no double reading with a postnotification.

I did that because I couldn't get programmatically the stackview new size when the labels are in... maybe creating a UIStackView subclass and get into its `layoutSubviews` could be the trick ?

This solution should **work as a workaround** but I don't know the reason why this behavior appears with a UIStackview.

==========

**EDIT (solution)**

The problem is the way the `titleView` of the `navigationItem` is created. The best way to achieve your purpose is to :

- Initialize your titleView as a simple `UIView` whose frame is the same as the stackview's.
- Add the stackview as a subview after having specified its frame and its accessibility properties.

Follow the steps hereafter in your code :

- Add the `.header` trait in the stackview property :

  ```
  private lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
      let stackView = UIStackView(frame: .zero)
      stackView.axis = .vertical
      stackView.alignment = .center
      stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
      stackView.isAccessibilityElement = true
      stackView.accessibilityTraits = .header
      return stackView
  }()
  ```
- Change the stackview case in your 'switch...case...' code section as below :

  ```
  case .stackView:
      label.text = "UIStackView"
      label.sizeToFit()
      stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)

      label2.text = subtitle
      label2.sizeToFit()
      stackView.addArrangedSubview(label2)

      stackView.frame.size.width = max(label.frame.width, label2.frame.width)
      stackView.frame.size.height = label.frame.height + label2.frame.height

      stackView.accessibilityLabel = label.text?.appending(", \(label2.text!)")

      navigationItem.titleView = UIView(frame: stackView.frame)
      navigationItem.titleView?.addSubview(stackView)
  }
  ```

Now, the `postNotification` **reads out your stackview only once** as the first element of your screen.

Comment: I'm not sure your solution is correct. I can achieve the same results by not setting `stackView.accessibilityLabel` at all. I think that it is just defaulting to reading the label text, which is why it appears to work. I've updated the repo to use either a two line label with a custom accessibility label or a stack view containing two labels.

As for your suggestion of not focusing the title or reordering the elements, I will definitely give that some thought. In the meantime though, I still don't know why this issue is occurring.

Comment: I did try out your solution, but it still didn't resolve the issue. In the end I just left it as is. Thank you for trying!