# React Native Accessibility : On attaching accessibilityRole="header", voice over call it twice

Tags: react-native, accessibility, react-native-ios

`<div accessibilityRole="header" accessibilityLabel="Test Label">`
    `Test Label`
   `</div>`

accessibilityRole called twice by React Native Accessibility on Android and iOS

Expectation : should be called once **Test Label Header** and not **Test Label Header Header**

Comment: can you check if this fixes your issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954861/voiceover-reads-accessibility-label-twice-when-focusing-non-uilabel-titleview

Comment: I don't think we have `div` tag in Reach Native, please double check your questions

Comment: yes @TonyNguyen you are correct It is a 
```<SomeComponent accessibilityRole="header"
        accessibilityLabel='Test Label' ></SomeComponent >```

Comment: But for me still the issue is voice over calling twice

Comment: I am using Text Component here @TonyNguyen

Comment: <Text
        accessibilityRole="header"
        accessibilityLabel="Test Label"></Text>

Comment: @windmaomao I am using the text component in react-native, the mentioned URL is different

Comment: It's better to include a full simple code version of that, with this information, I don't think anyone can help.

Comment: this is my FULL CODE @TonyNguyen on which i am running Accessibility
 <Text  accessibilityRole="header"  accessibilityLabel="Test Label"> Test Label </Text>

Comment: That's not a full code, You better include the simple version of the component that you use that line of code too.