# Voiceover reads the UI Label again after changing volume

Tags: swift, accessibility, voiceover

I have a UI Label, which VoiceOver is focused on. It reads it. Then I change volume up or down, and then it reads the value of UI Label two more times. Any idea how to fix this? Or is this expected behaviour? So that it reads it only once? The UI Label is a **dynamic time counter**, so it changes every second.
If I don't change the volume, it reads it only once.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VoiceOver reads accessibility label twice when focusing non-UILabel titleView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954861/voiceover-reads-accessibility-label-twice-when-focusing-non-uilabel-titleview)